# How to split dynamically generated buttons into columns using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, multiple-columns

I have Javascript code that generates buttons  of two types. A header button then a varying amount of content buttons underneath. I was using CSS3 to split the buttons into columns with '-webkit-column-break' but this does not function properly in Internet Explorer or Safari.

I have an approach for custom Javascript in mind. I'm just wondering if it's possible, and how I might accomplish it. Here is my pseudo code;

```
create 3 divs - 1, 2, and 3

count header array.
divide count by 3 to find number to place in each column.

create a counter.
for each header placed increase count by 1.
if count is equal to column maximum then use div 2.
if div2 count is equal to column maximum then use div 3.
```

I can see that one problem with this approach is that it doesnt account for the varying number of columns underneath the headers. I would like column 1 and 2 to be equal length or all 3 to be equal if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Here's how I did it

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/T52E4/)

```
 var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";
mycars[3] = "Porsche";
mycars[4] = "Daewoo";
mycars[5] = "MG";

var arrayCount = mycars.length;

var columnLength = arrayCount / 3;

for (var i=0; i < mycars.length; i++)
{

if (i<columnLength)
{
      document.getElementById('carList').innerHTML += '<button class="countryButtons"> '+       mycars[i]+' </button><br />';
}
else if(i< columnLength*2)
{
 document.getElementById('carList2').innerHTML += '<button class="countryButtons"> '+    mycars[i]+' </button><br />';
 }
    else if(i< columnLength*3)
{
 document.getElementById('carList3').innerHTML += '<button class="countryButtons"> '+      mycars[i]+' </button><br />';
   }
  }
```